# preselected option value from database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-select

I have an edit form which contains `select option` input, I want to select the default option based on condition. Here it is :

```
<select class="form-control locationid" id="locationid" name="locationid" required>
   <option value="" disabled selected> Select branch</option>
   <option data-id="0" value="0">NONE</option>
        <?php foreach ($vendor as $v) { ?>
   <option data-id="<?php echo $v['location_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $v['location_id']?>" ><?php echo $v['name'] ;?></option>
        <?php };?> 
</select>
```

My controller :

```
$this->db->select("d.user_id as id, d.plate_number as plate_number, d.current_lat as lat, d.current_lon as lon, d.created_on as created_on, d.updated_on as updated_on, d.available as available, d.location_id as location_id, u.user_name as name, u.user_email as email, u.user_phone as phone, v.name as location_name");
        $this->db->from('user_driver as d');
        $this->db->join('user as u', 'd.user_id = u.user_id','left');
        $this->db->join('vendor_location as v', 'd.location_id = v.location_id','left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data['driver'] = $query->result_array();

        $this->db->select("location_id, name");
        $this->db->from('vendor_location');
        $query2 = $this->db->get();
        $data['vendor'] = $query2->result_array();
```

the `user_driver` table contains `location_id` column related to `location_id` column in `vendor_location` table. How can I make the `select option` showing the existing `location_id` from `user_driver` table as well as options from `vendor_location` table? For now, the code above only show the disabled option `Select branch`.

Comment: you want a default selected value based on what?

Comment: from the existing value in `user_driver` table column `location_id`. Since it is an `edit` form, it should be showing the existing value @SanoojT

Comment: since it is an edit form you have an id to do edit and i don't see any `$this->db->where('id',$id);` in your code for selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for getting selected options, but for this store `location_id` from `$data['driver']` in a separate array:

```
<?php
// in your view file
$location = array();
foreach ($driver as $value) { // getting from $data['driver']
  $location[] = $value['location_id']; // store all location_id in an array
}
?>
```

*Than use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) inside the `<option>` as like:*

```
<?=(in_array($v['location_id'], $location) ? 'selected=""' : '')?>
```

**Example:**

```
<select class="form-control locationid" id="locationid" name="locationid" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected> Select branch</option>
  <option data-id="0" value="0">NONE</option>
  <?php foreach ($vendor as $v) { ?>
    <option <?=(in_array($v['location_id'], $location) ? 'selected=""' : '')?> data-id="<?php echo $v['location_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $v['location_id']?>" ><?php echo $v['name'] ;?></option>
  <?php };?> 
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, never thought about storing the location value to empty array :)

Answer (score 1):

- First remove selected attribute from 'Select branch' option
- You can store all the location_ids in one array variable(eg. $locations_ids).
- using in_array inside foreach we can check whether location is present.

Refer code below -

```html
<select class="form-control locationid" id="locationid" name="locationid" required>
   <option value="" disabled > Select branch</option>
   <option data-id="0" value="0">NONE</option>
        <?php foreach ($vendor as $v) { ?>
   
   <option data-id="<?php echo $v['location_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $v['location_id']?>" <?php echo in_array($v['location_id'], $locations_ids) ? 'selected' : ''; ><?php echo $v['name'] ;?></option>
    
        <?php };?> 
</select>
```